# Add field in Default View of the List while creating using Add-PnPFieldFromXml command

Tags: sharepoint-online, view, pnp-powershell, default

I am creating a field in SharePoint list using **Add-PnPFieldFromXml** command

The field is created successfully. I want to add this field to the default view of the list using the same command.

I checked [Add-PnPFieldFromXml](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/add-pnpfieldfromxml?view=sharepoint-ps) link but did not find the option to add the column in the default view.

How can I achieve the above requirement?

Or do I have to use [Set-PnPView](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/set-pnpview?view=sharepoint-ps) command?

**Update**

below is the code I am using.

```
  $listTitle = "Test"
  $listUrl = "Test"
  Remove-PnPList -Identity $listTitle
  Write-Host -ForegroundColor Magenta "Creating list: " $listURL
  New-PnPList -Title $listTitle -Url $listUrl -Template "GenericList"
  $FieldXML= "<Field Type='Note' Name='CustomField' ID='$([GUID]::NewGuid())' DisplayName='CustomField' Viewable ='TRUE' Required ='FALSE' RichText='FALSE'></Field>"
  Add-PnPFieldFromXml -List $listTitle -FieldXml $FieldXML
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**:

Try adding `Viewable = "TRUE"` in Field XML.

**Example**:

```
$xml = '<Field Type="Text"
          Name="PSCmdletTest"
          DisplayName="PSCmdletTest"
          ID="{27d81055-f208-41c9-a976-61c5473eed4a}"
          Group="Test"
          Required="FALSE"
          StaticName="PSCmdletTest"
          Viewable="TRUE"
        />'

Add-PnPFieldFromXml -List "Demo List" -FieldXml $xml
```

**Documentation**: [Field element (Field)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/field-element-field).

> **Viewable**:     Optional **Boolean**. **TRUE** to specify that the field is added to the default view. The default value is **TRUE**.

**Solution 2**:

You can also set the fields to show in SharePoint list view using `Set-PnPView`.

**Example**:

```
Set-PnPView -List "Documents" -Identity "Corporate Documents" -Fields "Title","Created"
```

**Documentation**: [Set-PnPView](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/set-pnpview).

Comment: It is not working. I have added the code in the question

Comment: Strange. According to microsoft documentation it should work. If it is not working then try using `Set-PnPView` (see updated answer).

Answer (score 1):

Modify your PnP PowerShell as below.

```
$URL='https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/test'
Connect-PnPOnline –Url $URL –Credentials (Get-Credential)
$listTitle = "Test"
$listUrl = "Test"
Remove-PnPList -Identity $listTitle
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Magenta "Creating list: " $listURL
New-PnPList -Title $listTitle -Url $listUrl -Template GenericList
$FieldXML= "<Field Type='Note' Name='CustomField' ID='$([GUID]::NewGuid())' DisplayName='CustomField' Viewable ='TRUE' Required ='FALSE' RichText='FALSE'></Field>"
Add-PnPFieldFromXml -List $listTitle -FieldXml $FieldXML
$AllItemsView = Get-PnPView -List $listTitle -Identity "All Items"
$AllItemsView.ViewFields.Add("CustomField")
$AllItemsView.Update()
Invoke-PnPQuery
```